# Best practise for updating / managing HTML pages

Tags: html, content-management-system

I am developing an e-commerce website as part of an assignment and am wondering what is the best practise for updating a collection of webpages.

I currently have one index.html page for the news etc. and then I copied and pasted the file and edited as i needed for the shopping cart functionality.

My question is; if I need to update something on the index.html file and which that change to show in all the pages, is there an easy / convenient way to update all of the pages together if I have a large amount instead of updating them manually one by one?

Answer (score 1):

This is where the rubber meets the road for most developers. Now you are seeing a need to update something once and have that change propagate out to some / elements / pages. This is where making things "dynamic" and "modular" start to make sense and is the very reason server side scripting languages such as PHP were created. This in addition to a database such as mysql can create powerful, data driven websites and applications. HTML is just markup, all sites use it, but it by itself isn't able to take advantage of the benefits of being a dynamic language.

A great place to start looking for a content management system is by using something that has a lot of support / community behind it to help with the questions you will have along the way.  It is also a good place to ease in to dynamic languages like php. I suggest using something like wordpress (wordpress.org) to get started. It handles most / all of the heavy lifting in regards to structure and all you really need to do is worry about the presentation of your site (themes). You'll only need something like MAMP (for mac) or XAMMP (for win) in order to make a local server (php / mysql) so you can install wordpress. There is a TON of resources and tutorials, plugins, themes, community support.

Edit : 
Since you are limited to the client side. Alternatively, if you know javascript, you could look into a javascript MVC framework and use client side templates like handlebars, .EJS etc.

Good luck & Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however the project only allows client-side programming. I should have mentioned this in my question... is there anything that can be done?

Comment: Doh.. Ok, well carry on with the way you were doing it. Without dynamic capabilities you will have to update each one manually. You COULD be sneaky and name your pages .SHTML and use server side includes like : <!--#include file="header.html" --> in the markup to include smaller chunks of the page in each page. But if thats against the project guidelines you may be stuck.

Alternatively, if you know javascript, you could look into a javascript MVC framework and use client side templates like handlebars, .EJS etc.